# Magento 1.9 and mongoDB using Cm_Mongo

Tags: magento-1.9, mongo

I'm a newbie magento, I'm trying to research how to integrate between magento and mongodb, but documents about it in Internet seems not more. I've found this community extension https://github.com/colinmollenhour/magento-mongo and trying this but somethings not working. I want to ask somebody who used this and give me some advices or tutorials for do it. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Stick to Magento + MySql to learn how the system works and then move on to MongoDb once you hav more experience. This advice will save you some sleep nights.